# How to add solids to upper test tube and make greyscale?

Tags: xetex, pstricks

Hello I do make the following TeX image greyscale. I would also like to have some black solids in the test tube above the bunsen burner. Currently I have this:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm,substance={\pstBULLES[20]{white}},niveauLiquide1=0}
\pstChauffageTube[barbotage,pince]
\end{document}
```

Which produces this image (you have to use XeTeX to have it render properly, there are workarounds for using other pdf formats with pstricks but I didn't include it in this code to make it simple):

[image]

Here is a annotation of what I want (I also want it to be greyscale).

[image]

Comment: Perhaps that's just me but to me these two figures look identical.

Comment: There are black substances in the test tube at the top of the second image. I would also like the final image to be greyscale

Comment: OK, now I see it. ;-)

Comment: I want the flame to be over the solids btw which I do not know how to do in tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not an answer but maybe a starting point. I think it does not show any stuff in the left tube because you set `niveauLiquide1` to 0. If you leave it at its default but change the color to white you can add stuff. <s>What remains to be done is to find the right substance.</s> **UPDATE**: Added an arguably better substance.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\newpsstyle{aspectLiquideFake}{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white}
\psset{unit=0.5cm,substance={\pstBULLES[50]{gray}}}
\pstChauffageTube[barbotage,pince,substance={\pstGrenailleZinc[80]},aspectLiquide1=aspectLiquideFake]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: lol I just decided to draw it in TikZ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442281/how-to-add-solids-in-tikz and now I have the same problem as to how to add the substance.

Comment: @sabhoque Such is life ;-) I personally think that on the long run you may be better off with Ti*k*Z. (Don't get me wrong, I was happily using PSTricks for many many years and am still stunned by its abilities and very grateful to Herbert and the others for keeping it alive. But given the compilation time of that and the fact that in the manual some important statements are cut at the right end, one may start translating these great things to Ti*k*Z, which can be compiled with pdflatex and much quicker, and for which one gets more and better answers in this forum.)

Comment: I couldn't agree less even though I have not been using LaTeX, TikZ and PSTricks for very long.